# How can I include both relationship in a single request endpoint?

Tags: laravel

I have `User` model and `FieldReport` model. Each `User` may have a `FieldReport` as reporter, and also have one (or more) tagged by the other user. So far, I have created 2 relationships for both model;

`User.php`

```php
...

class User extends Model
{
    ...

    /**
     * Each user may have many field reports as reporter.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\HasMany
     */
    public function fieldReports()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FieldReport::class);
    }

    /**
     * Each user may also have field reports from other reporters
     * if they are tagged.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function taggedFieldReports()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(FieldReport::class, 'field_report_participant', 'participant_id');
    }

    ...
}
```

`FieldReport.php`

```php
...

class FieldReport extends Model
{
    /**
     * Each field report may belongs to a reporter.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsTo
     */
    public function reporter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Each field report may belongs to many tagged users.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function taggedUsers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'field_report_participant', 'field_report_id', 'participant_id');
    }

    ...
}
```

But I have problem when it comes to displaying the data, I can't show them both at once, so, is it possible to do this without making separate endpoint for each relationship? If possible, what approach I could use for this condition?

```php
    // FieldReport.php
    
    /**
     * Grab all registries based on client's role.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function registries()
    {
        $user = request()->user();

        // Customer might want to see what's happening on their companies, so be it.
        if ($user && $user->getRoleNames()->contains('customer')) {
            // TODO: Customer might want to to be able to filter the given data
            return $this;
        }

        return $user->fieldReports(); // what about the tagged one?
    }

    // FieldReportController.php

    public function index()
    {
        $reports = $this->model->registries()->latest()->paginate();
        return response()->json($reports);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Mudit's answer, it works fine but it forces me to include the user data and put the field reports separated with their relationship. What I really wanted is more or less like this... Is this possible?

```json
// Instead of this...
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jane Doe",
  "field_reports": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "title": "Hello",
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "title": "World",
    },
  ],
  "tagged_field_reports": [
    {
      "id": 128,
      "user_id": 3,
      "title": "Hello",
      "pivot": {
        "field_report_participant": {
          "field_report_id": 128,
          "user_id": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 335,
      "user_id": 12,
      "title": "Universe",
      "pivot": {
        "field_report_participant": {
          "field_report_id": 335,
          "user_id": 1
        }
      }
    },
  ],
}
 
// I want it to be more like this...
[
  {
    {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "title": "Hello",
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "title": "World",
    },
    {
      "id": 128,
      "user_id": 3,
      "title": "Hello",
      "pivot": {
        "field_report_participant": {
          "field_report_id": 128,
          "user_id": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 335,
      "user_id": 12,
      "title": "Universe",
      "pivot": {
        "field_report_participant": {
          "field_report_id": 335,
          "user_id": 1
        }
      }
    },
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is to have a `reports()` method on `User` model which will fetch a combined collection of `FieldReports` and `TaggedFieldReports`

```php
class User extends Model
{

    public function fieldReports()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FieldReport::class);
    }

    public function taggedFieldReports()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(FieldReport::class, 'field_report_participant', 'participant_id');
    }

    public function reports()
    {

        return $this->fieldReports->concat($this->taggedFieldReports);

        /** Or - With pagination - untested **/
        return $this->fieldReports->paginate(5)->concat($this->taggedFieldReports->paginate(5));
    }

}
    public 
 // FieldReport.php
    
    /**
     * Grab all registries based on client's role.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function registries()
    {
        $user = request()->user();

        // Customer might want to see what's happening on their companies, so be it.
        if ($user && $user->getRoleNames()->contains('customer')) {
            // TODO: Customer might want to to be able to filter the given data
            return $this;
        }

        return $user->reports(); // what about the tagged one?
    }

    // FieldReportController.php

    public function index()
    {
        //$reports = $this->model->registries()->latest()->paginate();
        $reports = $this->model->registries();
        return response()->json($reports);
    }
```

Collection methods like `chunk` or `take` can be used on unpaginated collection (first option) in the `registries()` method

Comment: Why would it use paginate twice on each relation? can't we just use this? `$this->fieldReports->concat($this->taggedFieldReports)->paginate(5);`

Comment: Not using paginate twice, rather it is using paginate individually on each relation before concatenating the collections into single one. However it is not necessary to use pagination. As mentioned `chunk` or `take` methods can be used on collection concatenated without paginating individual related model collections - if it suffices your needs

Comment: allright great, i got it now.. thanks for the explanation

Comment: Like you want to get all users and their reports? Or reports for all users? Yes you can approach it two ways. First using the declared `reports()` method you can get all users in the Controller and then map over the collection to attach reports for each user. Second one can define custom collection for a model https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#custom-collections

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Model::with('relation1','relation2')->paginate();` this will attach both relation with your collection.

For more information you can read the docs.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: doesn't it just for the related model? I want to retrieve the `fieldReports` and `taggedFieldReports`, both are defined on the user model.

Comment: User model has a relation with `fieldReports` and `taggedFieldReports` so you can do. `$user->with('taggedFieldReports','fieldReports')->latest()->paginate();`

Comment: allright, got it.. but what if I don't want to include the user object?

Comment: wait lemme bring some example

Comment: I understood your query but I will you differentiate between `fieldReports` and `taggedFieldReports` with the response you desire?

Comment: I don't think so.. I just want to make it easier to iterate and put both in one view

Comment: I'll try what you suggest and post if I found a way.